# DC-DC Inverter PVlib

Tags: pvlib

Helly everyone,

I have to model a pv system which is connected to an electrolyzer. A PV system produces DC output and the electrolyzer requires DC input. Therefore, it makes sense to use a DC-DC inverter. However, I cannot find a dc-dc inverter in the cec-inverter library of pvlib. Does anyone know of a dc-dc ivnerter in any of the pvlib libraries?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a DC-DC inverter; inverters take their name from "inverting" DC to produce AC, and so an inverter can only be DC-AC.  What you want is a DC-DC converter.

Unfortunately pvlib doesn't currently (as of v0.9.5) provide any parameters sets, or even any models, for DC-DC converters.  It might be a welcome feature addition if you have a specific model you'd like to see implemented.

Anton's pvpltools has some code for modeling generic power converters (i.e. not specifically DC-AC or DC-DC), but I'm not aware of any parameter sets for those functions.  https://github.com/adriesse/pvpltools-python/blob/master/pvpltools/power_conversion.py